# Extract chunks from the last git commit without re-committing original commit

Tags: git

Let's say I have a commit and I realise that I want to extract a small chunk from it and commit that small chunk as a separate commit.

I already know many ways to do this using multiple commands, one example is:

```
$ `git reset @^`
$ `git add -p`    # Stage all but the small chunks I want to extract
$ `git commit`    # Commit original (without the small chunks)
$ `git commit -a` # Commit the remaining chunks as a new commit
```

The problem is, I would like to do that *without having to manually stage and re-commit the first commit*. Obviously the commit hash will change, but I would like to avoid having to type the commands to stage and commit the initial commit.

In other words, I'm ideally looking for one git command that lets me at once:
- interactively select chunks from the last commit
- remove these chunks from the commit (keeping the original commit message)
- put these chunks onto the index so they're ready for me to commit

Does such a command exist?

Comment: In a single shot? No... but you could just `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, getting all your changes into the index and then do `git commit --interactive` so that you can decide what to do on a file-by-file basis.

Comment: Mmh, that's one step closer thanks, but the problem is, `git commit --interactive` only works on whole files and also I still have to fiddle to stage all but a couple small chunks (and I have to reuse the last commit message with `-C @{1}` but that's easy enough).

Comment: It would be almost perfect if there was an equivalent of `git commit -p -C @{1}` that let you interactively pick chunks from the *index* (in that case, a `git reset --soft @^ && git commit -p -C @{1}` would do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The shortest way I can think removes one command from your list:

```
git reset @^
git commit -p
git commit -a
```

However, from your remarks in the comments I think another thing you might find helpful is `git reset -p @^` - the hunks it shows are in reverse which might be a little confusing at times, but this allows you to selectively unstage changes from your last commit, enabling this kind of workflow:

```
git reset -p @^
# potentially more wrangling
git commit --amend
git commit -a
```